# How can I duplicate an array ? (with same size)

Tags: c

I want to create a new array with the same size of "chaine" but only after the function

```
 char chaine[Lenght];   //Lenght = 20
 function(chaine, sizeof(chaine));
```

When I called "function" the size of "chaine" is changing randomly.

The new array "chaine2" also needs to be full of " * " characters.

Let met try to explain with some printf :

```
     printf("chaine = %s\n", chaine);
```

will show on screen something like :   chaine = WORDS   (5 characters)

And i want "chaine2" to be shown like this :  chaine2 = *****   (5 stars)

I apologize for my english, thank you for reading

Comment: You did not initialize `chaine` and you failed to show the code in `function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `char` arrays are special, in the sense that they have a *size*, which you specify when you declare them, and a *length*, which depends on their contents.  The size of an array is the amount of memory that's been allocated to it.  The length of a string is the number of characters before a terminating null (`'\0'`).

```
some_func() {
  int len = 20;      // Size of the array
  char chaine[len];  // Uninitialized array of size 20.

  memset(chaine, '\0', sizeof(chaine)); // Init to all null chars, len = 0
  strcpy(chaine, "WORDS"); // Copy a string, len = 5

  char *chaine2 = function(chaine, sizeof(chaine));
  printf("%s\n", chaine2);
  free (chaine2);
}
```

When you pass an array to a function, it's treated like a pointer.  So `sizeof(str)` inside the function will always return the size of pointer-to-char, and *not* the size of the original array.  If you want to know how long the string is, make sure it's null-terminated and use `strlen()` like this:

```
char *function(char *str, int len) {
  // Assume str = "WORDS", len = 20.
  char *new_str = malloc(len); // Create a new string, size = 20

  memset(new_str, '\0', len);  // Initialize to nulls
  memset(new_str, '*', strlen(str)); // Copy 5 '*' chars, len = 5

  return new_str;  // Pointer to 20 bytes of memory: 5 '*' and 15 '\0'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *dup_and_fillStar(const char *src, const size_t size){
    char *p,*ret;
    ret=p=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
    while(*src++)
        *p++='*';
    *p = '\0';
    return ret;
}

#define Length  20

int main(void){
    char chaine[Length] = "WORDS"; 
    char *chaine2;

    chaine2 = dup_and_fillStar(chaine, sizeof(chaine));
    printf("chine = %s\n", chaine);
    printf("chine2 = %s\n", chaine2);
    free(chaine2);

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you're using C99 (and so are able to use variable length arrays).

If you want to create the array outside of `function()` (where `chaine` is still an array), you can simply do:

```
char chaine2[Lenght];
```

Or, probably better:

```
char chaine2[sizeof(chaine)];
```

If you're inside `function()`, note that `chaine` will be a pointer, since the compiler sees an array definition in a function parameter as a pointer to it's first element (if this is confusing, [remember that pointers are not arrays](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html))

So, even if function is defined like this:

```
function(char chaine[], size_t length) {
```

the compiler will see it as:

```
function(char *chaine, size_t length) {
```

Either way, you can create `chaine2` by saying:

```
    char chaine2[length];
```

but NOT

```
    char chaine2[sizeof(chaine)]; // DONT DO THIS
```

since the `sizeof` will return the size of the pointer instead of the size of the array.

However you create it, if you want to fill the new array with '*' characters, you can use [`memset()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/memset/):

```
 memset(chaine2,'*',sizeof(chaine2));
```

Comment: Remember that `chaine2[]` is allocated on the stack, so it will become invalid when the function returns.